# Falha ao Mesclar Android Manifest.xml com AdMob [UNITY]

Tags: xml, unity-5, admob, android-manifest, merge

O erro está presente quando tento dar build no meu jogo de Android no unity, ele simplesmente acusa erro e diz que nao foi possivel dar Merge no arquivo do AndroidManifest.xml.

Erro1

> AndroidSDKToolsException: Unable to merge android manifests. See the
>   Console for more details. 
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.DetectErrorsAndWarnings
>   (System.String logMessages, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String
>   javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand
>   (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String
>   workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit
>   waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[]
>   sdkToolCommand, System.String workingdir,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand
>   (System.String[] sdkToolCommand,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
>   System.String errorMsg)
>   UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.MergeManifests (System.String
>   target, System.String mainManifest, System.String[] libraryManifests,
>   UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.MergeManifests
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context,
>   System.String targetManifest, System.String mainManifest)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.Execute
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
>   (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Erro2

> Error: Error while saving blame file, build will continue Error: O
>   prefixo "tools" do atributo "tools:overrideLibrary" associado a um
>   tipo de elemento "uses-sdk" nÃ£o estÃ¡ vinculado.
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)